# Upload Sagemaker Model to S3 without encryption

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-kms, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I am training models in sagemaker with its Pytorch Module and Huggingface module.
When the training is done, It successfully uploads model artifacts into s3.

But the problem is the code automatically uploads the model with encryption though I did not give any encryption key.

If I go to s3 and check the file details, I found

```
Encryption key
AWS Key Management Service key (SSE-KMS)
```

But I do not want encryption. Because I copy this artefact to another s3 on a different AWS, it creates a problem and needs extra permission.
Can anyone say, How to save the model without encryption in S3 from sageamaker?

I am using these modules

```
from sagemaker.huggingface import HuggingFace
from sagemaker.pytorch import PyTorch
```

Comment: How I solved it by copying data again in CDK. It removes the encryption as the bucket does not have the encryption policy.  Though I had to accept an unnecessary copy here.

for cli command is something  -> aws s3 cp source source.